# How to return a variable with number of tags using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to filter my data retrieved from ajax

```
      var csvf = data.filter(function (el) {
          return ['TRUCK_CPX'].indexOf(el.TAG) >= 0
          && ['CA5533'].indexOf(el.Chave) >= 0

               });
```

All I have to do is create a dynamic function to do something like that:

```
function datafilter(x, y) {
// I don't know what to do here //
}
```

For:

```
var csvf = data.filter(function (el) {

//Using one tag://
function datafilter('TAG:"TRUCK_CPX"');  });

//return ['TRUCK_CPX'].indexOf(el.TAG) >= 0//

//Using two tags://
function datafilter('TAG:"TRUCK_CPX"', 'Chave:"CA5533"');  });

//return ['TRUCK_CPX'].indexOf(el.TAG) >= 0 && ['CA5533'].indexOf(el.Chave) >= 0//
```

Anyone here know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that takes two arguments: an object, and the element.

- Map each key in the object to a space of the result of the condition
- Then, reduce the resulting array of booleans.

```
function filter(item, el) {
    return Object.keys(item).map(function(key) {
        return [item[key]].indexOf(el[key]) >= 0
    })
    .reduce(function(prev, memo) {
        return prev && memo;
    }, true);
}

const matchInverse = filter(
    {glue: 'gabby', alpha: 'allison'}, 
    {alpha: 'allison', glue: 'gabby'}
);

console.log(matchInverse);

var csvf = data.filter(filter(item, el));
```